# Labeling "a" and "b" on figure with multiple "\includegraphics" (without using actual "subfigure" entries)

Tags: graphics, labels, subfig

I wish to add two panels to a single figures as follows, without using "subfigure" entries:

```
  \begin{figure}[t!]
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figa.eps}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figb.eps}
  \caption{{a. Bla bla bla. b. Bla bla.}} 
  \label{Fig1}
  \end{figure}
```

How can I position the marks "a." and "b." at the bottom left corner of each panel (respectively) in this construction?

I do not wish to use "subfigures" per-se, if possible, since the current way above to have two plots in one figure is simply much less cumbersome.

Comment: Think of each image as a one word sentence in a paragraph.  If you add `a.\newline` and `b.\newline` after each image, they will appear as additional sentences.  `\caption` begins and ends with a `\par`.  (Actually, the `\newline` is just to avoid undefull `\hbox`)

Comment: @ John          Great, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t!]
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figa.eps}
  a. Bla bla bla.
  
  \bigskip
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{Figb.eps}
  b. Bla bla.

  \caption{A figure with two subfigures}\label{Fig1}
  \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect :), thanks.